# How to make Layout unfocusable ? (multitouch)

Tags: android, user-interface, sdk

I hava a problem that can be presented like this : I have a `RelativeLayout` filling the screen and inside it a `Button`. Under this layout I have an other `Button` (this is like a layer structure).

```
<Button android:layout_marginLeft="133dp" id="button_single"/>

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button id="button_inside"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I keep pressed the button `button_inside` it gives the focus to the layout so the `button_single` is no more clickable.

How can I disable the layout focusable ability ?

Thank you in advance

NOTE : in reality, in my project, the button_single is a `GLSurfaceView` filling the screen but the problem is the same.

Answer (score 1):

add

```
android:focusable="true" or "false"
```

in the xml file at your component

Comment: I've aleady tried, it does not works... I think the solution is something really specific because I've looked for hours :-/
Actually I've tried with all these : `android:clickable="false"`
     `android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"`
     `android:duplicateParentState="false"`
     `android:focusable="false"`
     `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`
     `android:longClickable="false"`